# Cant load a class model in my main app sinatra controller, unless I require it

Tags: web-applications, sinatra, structure

I´m building a sinatra app and when I call an instance of a model class in my, main app controller it says: NameError at /play
uninitialized constant RPS::Game, unless I require the Game model in my app controller. Why does it happen?

Comment: Hi, welcome on stack overflow, please have a look at the help center on how to properly ask questions, especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in your case.

Comment: Well, to use classes in Ruby, you need to require them first. In Rails this is done for you by the rails magic, but Sinatra is a very barebones framework and requires more manual labor, so to speak.